# build ros on mac opencv3 qt5core error

Tags: ros, mac

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I build ros on mac by referring this doc

and this error occur:

but I can found my Qt5Core in
sudo find /usr -name Qt5Core :/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.8.0_2/lib/cmake/Qt5Core

```
==> Processing plain cmake package: 'opencv3'
==> Building with env: '/Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
==> cmake /Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/src/opencv3 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3/install'
-- FP16: Feature disabled
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:18 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
    qt5core-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:556 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:19 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Gui.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
    qt5gui-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Gui" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Gui_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Gui"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:556 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:20 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:556 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:21 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Test.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Test", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Test" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5TestConfig.cmake
    qt5test-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Test" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Test_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Test" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:556 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:22 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Concurrent.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Concurrent", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Concurrent"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt5ConcurrentConfig.cmake
    qt5concurrent-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Concurrent" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Concurrent_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Concurrent" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:556 (include)


CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1318 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:34 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:556 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3/install/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3/install/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'opencv3':
  Command '['/Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/src/opencv3', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3 && /Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/src/opencv3 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262252/build-ros-on-mac-opencv3-qt5core-error/) by [westeast](https://answers.ros.org/users/30354/westeast/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem ,by add 'qt bin dir ` to path

strange.......

---

Originally posted by [westeast](https://answers.ros.org/users/30354/westeast/) with karma: 51 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rasika](https://answers.ros.org/users/38891/rasika/) on 2019-01-25**:
Hello,
I am also running into same error while compiling ROS kinetic on ubuntu 16.04 on running on virtual machine.
Can you elaborate more how you solved this problem?